# exploring avaliable commands in an applescript program

Tags: applescript

I have an application and I can do the following command on (I know this because I googled for it):

```
tell app "TextMate" to reload bundles
```

What I would really like is to be able to ask the "TextMate" program:

```
tell app "TextMate" to list all commands
```

and have it list out all the things I can ask it to do:

```
... 'reload bundles', 'exit', 'open files'...
```

is there a way to do that with applescript?

Answer (score 2):

The way to find all the commands of an app is to open its dictionary in your script editor. Usually "Open Dictionary ... " in the File menu, or drop the application onto the script editor.

**[EDIT]**

For applications that have AppleScript support, you can actually script opening the app itself with the Script Editor, a la:

```
set pathToApp to (choose file of type "APPL")
tell application "Script Editor"
 open pathToApp
end tell
```

BUT this will be problematic with a non-scriptable app. You'll get an error, but Script Editor will actually open some part of the app (and it will be slow about it), then give you an unusable document. There's no way to catch this error. If you use the Smile script editor, you can use this method ...

```
set p to (choose file of type "APPL")
try
    OpenDictionary(alias (p as string))
on error e

end try
```

... to open the dictionary of an app, and if it doesn't work (if the app doesn't have a dictionary), it returns an error but doesn't do anything else (but again, you can't catch the error and not have it complain, without hacking Smile)

**[EDIT 2]**

A rabbit hole to go down is trying System Events or the Finder to check for boolean of `has scripting terminology` property of a process, but I don't recommend it because I haven't found it to be reliable.

**[EDIT 3]**

Ach! I knew there was another method, but forgot what it was. As @mklement0 points out (thank you), you can do this to check for an app's script-ability prior to opening the app in Script Editor:

```
set pathToApp to (choose file of type "APPL") as text
set isScriptable to false
try
    class of application pathToApp
    -- only AppleScriptable applications have a class property 
    set isScriptable to true
end try

isScriptable
```

Comment: oh nice! is there a way to programmatically do "open dictionary"?

Comment: Also, I had a look at the dictionary of text mate and not all the commands are in there. the only method in there is `getUrl`

Comment: Hi @zcaudate. Sorry about the delay. If memory serves, TextMate beta 2 has hardly any scripting support whereas the 1.5 version's version is fairly extensive. But I would recommend Tex-Edit Plus (if you want formatted text) or TextWrangler. Both of these have excellent AS support.

Comment: You can test an application object for properties that only AppleScriptable apps have; e.g., `class`, such as in the following snippet: `set isScriptable to false ¬
try ¬
 class of application appName ¬
 set isScriptable to true ¬
end try
` (replace `¬` with actual line breaks, set `appName` to the target app name beforehand). Slight caveat: If the target application is NOT scriptable, this code will invariable _launch_ it.